# Make a certain button appear when 2 radio buttons are pressed

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a button appear when a certain combination of radio buttons are checked.

When I press 2 radio buttons by example, no buttons show up even tho I made a if and multiple elsif for all the possiblilities. I want that when more than 2 radio buttons are chose that the right buttoon for the right combination shows up where the button "Commencer" is.

[My program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kt4f.png)
My code:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim time As Integer
Dim score As Integer

'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/step-2-create-a-random-addition-problem?view=vs-2017'

Private Sub lblEquations_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblEquations.Click

End Sub

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
    lblSecondes.Text = time
    time = time - 1

    If time = -1 Then
        Timer.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    time = 10

    cmdCommencer1to12Divi.Visible = False
    cmdCommencer1to6Divi.Visible = False
    cmdCommencer6to12Divi.Visible = False
    cmdCommencer1to12Multi.Visible = False
    cmdCommencer1to6Multi.Visible = False
    cmdCommencer6to12Multi.Visible = False
    cmdCommencer1to12Plus.Visible = False
    cmdCommencer1to6plus.Visible = False
    cmdCommencer6to12Plus.Visible = False
    cmdCommencer1to12Sous.Visible = False
    cmdCommencer1to6Sous.Visible = False
    cmdCommencer6to12Sous.Visible = False


    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'


    If RadBut1a12.Checked And RadButAddition.Checked = True Then
        cmdCommencer1to12Plus.Visible = True

        cmdCommencer1to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Sous.Visible = False

    ElseIf RadBut1a12.Checked And RadButDivision.Checked = True Then
        cmdCommencer1to12Divi.Visible = True

        cmdCommencer1to6Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Sous.Visible = False

    ElseIf RadBut1a12.Checked And RadButMultiplication.Checked = True Then
        cmdCommencer1to12Multi.Visible = True

        cmdCommencer1to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Sous.Visible = False

    ElseIf RadBut1a12.Checked And RadButSoustraction.Checked = True Then
        cmdCommencer1to12Sous.Visible = True

        cmdCommencer1to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Sous.Visible = False


        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'


    ElseIf RadBut1a6.Checked And RadButAddition.Checked = True Then
        cmdCommencer1to6plus.Visible = True

        cmdCommencer1to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Sous.Visible = False

    ElseIf RadBut1a6.Checked And RadButDivision.Checked = True Then
        cmdCommencer1to6Divi.Visible = True

        cmdCommencer1to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Sous.Visible = False

    ElseIf RadBut1a6.Checked And RadButMultiplication.Checked = True Then
        cmdCommencer1to6Multi.Visible = True

        cmdCommencer1to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Sous.Visible = False

    ElseIf RadBut1a6.Checked And RadButSoustraction.Checked = True Then
        cmdCommencer1to6Sous.Visible = True

        cmdCommencer1to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Sous.Visible = False


        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'


    ElseIf RadBut6a12.Checked And RadButAddition.Checked = True Then
        cmdCommencer6to12Plus.Visible = True

        cmdCommencer1to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Sous.Visible = False

    ElseIf RadBut6a12.Checked And RadButDivision.Checked = True Then
        cmdCommencer6to12Divi.Visible = True

        cmdCommencer1to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Sous.Visible = False

    ElseIf RadBut6a12.Checked And RadButMultiplication.Checked = True Then
        cmdCommencer6to12Multi.Visible = True

        cmdCommencer1to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Sous.Visible = False

    ElseIf RadBut6a12.Checked And RadButSoustraction.Checked = True Then
        cmdCommencer6to12Sous.Visible = True

        cmdCommencer1to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Divi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Multi.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer6to12Plus.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to12Sous.Visible = False
        cmdCommencer1to6Sous.Visible = False

    End If
End Sub



Public Sub StartQuiz1to6Plus()
    addend1 = randomizer.Next(6)
    addend2 = randomizer.Next(6)

    lblEquations.Text = addend1.ToString() & " + " & addend2.ToString()
End Sub

Public Sub StartQuiz6to12Plus()
    addend1 = randomizer.Next(6, 12)
    addend2 = randomizer.Next(6, 12)

    lblEquations.Text = addend1.ToString() & " + " & addend2.ToString()
End Sub

Public Sub StartQuiz1to12Plus()
    addend1 = randomizer.Next(12)
    addend2 = randomizer.Next(12)

    lblEquations.Text = addend1.ToString() & " + " & addend2.ToString()
End Sub



'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

Public Sub StartQuiz1to6Sous()
    addend1 = randomizer.Next(6)
    addend2 = randomizer.Next(6)

    lblEquations.Text = addend1.ToString() & " - " & addend2.ToString()
End Sub

Public Sub StartQuiz6to12Sous()
    addend1 = randomizer.Next(6, 12)
    addend2 = randomizer.Next(6, 12)

    lblEquations.Text = addend1.ToString() & " - " & addend2.ToString()
End Sub

Public Sub StartQuiz1to12Sous()
    addend1 = randomizer.Next(12)
    addend2 = randomizer.Next(12)

    lblEquations.Text = addend1.ToString() & " - " & addend2.ToString()
End Sub

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

Public Sub StartQuiz1to6Multi()
    addend1 = randomizer.Next(6)
    addend2 = randomizer.Next(6)

    lblEquations.Text = addend1.ToString() & " x " & addend2.ToString()
End Sub

Public Sub StartQuiz6to12Multi()
    addend1 = randomizer.Next(6, 12)
    addend2 = randomizer.Next(6, 12)

    lblEquations.Text = addend1.ToString() & " x " & addend2.ToString()
End Sub

Public Sub StartQuiz1to12Multi()
    addend1 = randomizer.Next(12)
    addend2 = randomizer.Next(12)

    lblEquations.Text = addend1.ToString() & " x " & addend2.ToString()
End Sub

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

Public Sub StartQuiz1to6Divi()
    addend1 = randomizer.Next(6)
    addend2 = randomizer.Next(6)

    lblEquations.Text = addend1.ToString() & "  " & addend2.ToString()
End Sub

Public Sub StartQuiz6to12Divi()
    addend1 = randomizer.Next(6, 12)
    addend2 = randomizer.Next(6, 12)

    lblEquations.Text = addend1.ToString() & "  " & addend2.ToString()
End Sub

Public Sub StartQuiz1to12Divi()
    addend1 = randomizer.Next(12)
    addend2 = randomizer.Next(12)

    lblEquations.Text = addend1.ToString() & "  " & addend2.ToString()
End Sub








Private randomizer As New Random()

Private addend1 As Integer
Private addend2 As Integer

Public Sub TimerReset()
    time = 10
End Sub

Private Sub txtReponse_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtReponse.TextChanged
    If txtReponse.Text = (addend1 + addend2) Then
        TimerReset()
        score = score + 1
        lblScore.Text = score
        StartQuiz1to6Plus()
        txtReponse.Text = ""

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdQuitter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdQuitter.Click
    End
End Sub

Private Sub cmdRestart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdRestart.Click
    Timer.Enabled = False
    TimerReset()
    lblEquations.Text = ""
    lblScore.Text = ""
    lblSecondes.Text = ""
    txtReponse.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCommencer1to6plus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCommencer1to6plus.Click
    If cmdCommencer1to6plus.Text = "Commencer" Then
        cmdCommencer1to6plus.Text = "Arrêter"

        TimerReset()
        Timer.Enabled = True
        StartQuiz1to6Plus()

        If time = 0 Then
            Timer.Enabled = False
        End If


    ElseIf cmdCommencer1to6plus.Text = "Arrêter" Then
        TimerReset()
        Timer.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCommencer1to12Divi_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCommencer1to12Divi.Click
    If cmdCommencer1to12Divi.Text = "Commencer" Then
        cmdCommencer1to12Divi.Text = "Arrêter"

        TimerReset()
        Timer.Enabled = True
        StartQuiz1to12Divi()

        If time = 0 Then
            Timer.Enabled = False
        End If


    ElseIf cmdCommencer1to12Divi.Text = "Arrêter" Then
        TimerReset()
        Timer.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCommencer6to12Divi_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCommencer6to12Divi.Click

End Sub

Private Sub cmdCommencer1to6Divi_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCommencer1to6Divi.Click

End Sub

Private Sub cmdCommencer1to12Multi_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCommencer1to12Multi.Click

End Sub

Private Sub cmdCommencer6to12Multi_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCommencer6to12Multi.Click

End Sub

Private Sub cmdCommencer1to6Multi_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCommencer1to6Multi.Click

End Sub

Private Sub cmdCommencer1to12Sous_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCommencer1to12Sous.Click

End Sub

Private Sub cmdCommencer6to12Sous_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCommencer6to12Sous.Click

End Sub

Private Sub cmdCommencer1to6Sous_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCommencer1to6Sous.Click

End Sub

Private Sub cmdCommencer1to12Plus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCommencer1to12Plus.Click

End Sub

Private Sub cmdCommencer6to12Plus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCommencer6to12Plus.Click

End Sub

Private Sub RadButAddition_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadButAddition.CheckedChanged

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: In addition to providing some code that shows what you are doing and an explanation of what about it isn't working, please also specify which UI framework you are using.

Comment: Radio buttons are supposed to be mutually exclusives. Maybe you're thinking about checkboxes??

Comment: 2 different radio buttons in 2 different group boxes

Comment: The if/elseif blocks are all in the `Form.Load` event handler, so it only gets called at start-up.  There seems to be no code for the `CheckChanged` events of any of the radio button controls.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh okk... Thanks... I think I know what I did wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, we'll keep it simple, as you're obviously a beginner. You can ask questions if you feel like you don't understand what I'm saying.

Place you button on your Form, but set it invisible.

[image: .Visible = False]

Since Radio buttons are normally mutually exclusives, I'll continue using CheckBoxes, but you can use the same code with radio buttons with minor changes.

Add this event to each checkbox:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    CheckForCheckBoxCombinaison()
End Sub
```

This event will call the Sub handling the check. You could have written it right in the event handler, but you would have had to copy and paste it several times and you don't want to copy and paste code at several places in the same project as a rule of thumb.

Now create that other Sub we're calling:

```
Private Sub CheckForCheckBoxCombinaison()
    If CheckBox1.Checked AndAlso CheckBox3.Checked Then
        Button1.Visible = True
    Else
        Button1.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Yay, have fun.

Comment: Ohhhhh okk... Normally I program in Python, PHP, CSS and HTML sooo yahhh I just started in VB. Thank you!

Comment: Don't mind me, the base question let me think you were at the beginning but I meant well. Also, have fun!

Comment: @LoukaPapineau the way to thank laancelot is to accept his answer with the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.